# iOS networking (speed and traffic) optimizations

Tags: ios, networking, optimization

Lets say we have an app which communicates with a server very intensive (several requests in a second). The requests sent within the same second are independent.

What kind of ways to improve speed of data interchange and to minimize traffic can you suggest?
Could you tell how to implement each one.

PS:
**I received this question at interview with my employer, thus I can't make it more specific. I presented it "as is"**

Comment: What sort of protocol are you using?

Comment: @nduplessis assume it is http. anyway i'd like to get some conceptual suggestions

Comment: Unless you get much more specific in your question, the Grand Poobahs of SO are going to close your question ASAP...

Comment: @sangony I presented the question in the form in which I received it from my employer at interview. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Best advice - do not do that. Request are expensive. Optimize if possible. Send and receive as many data possible (and reasonable) in one request. If not possible try to use compression in HTTP (usually gzip), minimize server response (omit blank spaces, ....), use cache where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with igo, optimise on your protocol instead. Use a persistent TCP socket, look into something like Google's protocol buffers (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Answer (score 1):

Very open general question so hard to know what parameters to go by. But...

1) Use JSON instead of XML for test transmissions.

2) Never display more data than absolutely required. In other words if you only need to display text, do it without displaying the additional picture.

3) Use strong compression when transmitting images. `NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, compression);`

4) Use asynchronous transmissions and blocks.

5) Use TCP and don't mess with it.

6) Try to group your data as much as possible into a single transmission.